# SPFx & PnPjs People picker issues

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, pnp-js

Trying to develop a webpart with PnP people picker

(in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400]  ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected."}}}

Anyone knows what exactly to send during POST method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done... Add ensureuser = {true} in JSX...